# Как создать зависимые списки select2.js?

Tags: javascript

есть два селекта

```
<select id="category" class="form-control" name="category_id">
   <option value="Уборка и помощь по хозяйству">Уборка и помощь по хозяйству</option>
   <option value="Виртиуальный помощник">Виртиуальный помощник</option>
   <option value="Компьютернная помощь">Компьютернная помощь</option>
</select>
```

и

```
<select id="sub_category" class="form-control" name="sub_category_id"></select>
```

вот так подключаю их к  select2

```
$('#category').select2({ placeholder: "Выберите из списка",allowClear: true,language: "ru",});
$('#sub_category').select2({ placeholder: "Выберите из списка",allowClear: true, language: "ru"});
```

Пытаюсь найти как  сделать зависимые списки при помощи плагина select2. Те надо при выборе категории получать по ajax  данные под категорий и вставлять во второй список . Пытался гуглить нет информации. Интересует формат ответа, у куда вставлять данные.

Answer (score 0):

В доках написано: https://select2.org/data-sources/ajax, атрибут `data`. По ajax запросу возвращаются данные, которые можно записать их в данный атрибут

```
$('#mySelect2').select2({
  ajax: {
    url: 'https://api.github.com/orgs/select2/repos',
    data: function (params) {
      var query = {
        search: params.term,
        type: 'public'
      }

      // Query parameters will be ?search=[term]&type=public
      return query;
    }
  }
});
```

Ещё пример

```
$("#profiles-thread").select2({
    minimumInputLength: 2,
    tags: [],
    ajax: {
        url: URL,
        dataType: 'json',
        type: "GET",
        quietMillis: 50,
        data: function (term) {
            return {
                term: term
            };
        },
        results: function (data) {
            return {
                results: $.map(data, function (item) {
                    return {
                        text: item.completeName,
                        slug: item.slug,
                        id: item.id
                    }
                })
            };
        }
    }
});
```

---

Если лень самому делать, то можете воспользоваться [готовым классом](https://gist.github.com/ajaxray/187e7c9a00666a7ffff52a8a69b8bf31). Пример: https://codepen.io/ajaxray/full/oBPbQe/

```js
/**
 * A Javascript module to loadeding/refreshing options of a select2 list box using ajax based on selection of another select2 list box.
 * 
 * @url : https://gist.github.com/ajaxray/187e7c9a00666a7ffff52a8a69b8bf31
 * @auther : Anis Uddin Ahmad <anis.programmer@gmail.com>
 * 
 * Live demo - https://codepen.io/ajaxray/full/oBPbQe/
 * w: http://ajaxray.com | t: @ajaxray
 */
var Select2Cascade = (function(window, $) {

  function Select2Cascade(parent, child, url, select2Options) {
    var afterActions = [];
    var options = select2Options || {};

    // Register functions to be called after cascading data loading done
    this.then = function(callback) {
      afterActions.push(callback);
      return this;
    };

    parent.select2(select2Options).on("change", function(e) {

      child.prop("disabled", true);

      var _this = this;
      $.getJSON(url.replace(':parentId:', $(this).val()), function(items) {
        var newOptions = '<option value="">-- Select --</option>';
        for (var id in items) {
          newOptions += '<option value="' + id + '">' + items[id] + '</option>';
        }

        child.select2('destroy').html(newOptions).prop("disabled", false)
          .select2(options);

        afterActions.forEach(function(callback) {
          callback(parent, child, items);
        });
      });
    });
  }

  return Select2Cascade;

})(window, $);

$(document).ready(function() {
  var select2Options = {
    width: 'resolve'
  };
  // Loading raw JSON files of a secret gist - https://gist.github.com/ajaxray/32c5a57fafc3f6bc4c430153d66a55f5
  var apiUrl = 'https://gist.githubusercontent.com/ajaxray/32c5a57fafc3f6bc4c430153d66a55f5/raw/260a653e6347fb6d2360e8ec376a2dc4888c1afa/:parentId:.json';

  $('select').select2(select2Options);
  var cascadLoading = new Select2Cascade($('#type'), $('#subtype'), apiUrl, select2Options);
  cascadLoading.then(function(parent, child, items) {
    // Dump response data
    console.log(items);
  });
});
```

```css
/* Space out content a bit */

body {
  padding-top: 20px;
  padding-bottom: 20px;
}


/* Everything but the jumbotron gets side spacing for mobile first views */

.header,
.marketing,
.footer {
  padding-right: 15px;
  padding-left: 15px;
}


/* Custom page header */

.header {
  padding-bottom: 20px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #e5e5e5;
}


/* Make the masthead heading the same height as the navigation */

.header h3 {
  margin-top: 0;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  line-height: 40px;
}


/* Custom page footer */

.footer {
  padding-top: 19px;
  color: #777;
  border-top: 1px solid #e5e5e5;
}


/* Customize container */

@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .container {
    max-width: 730px;
  }
}

.container-narrow>hr {
  margin: 30px 0;
}


/* Supporting marketing content */

.marketing {
  margin: 40px 0;
}

.marketing p+h4 {
  margin-top: 28px;
}


/* Responsive: Portrait tablets and up */

@media screen and (min-width: 768px) {
  /* Remove the padding we set earlier */
  .header,
  .marketing,
  .footer {
    padding-right: 0;
    padding-left: 0;
  }
  /* Space out the masthead */
  .header {
    margin-bottom: 30px;
  }
  /* Remove the bottom border on the jumbotron for visual effect */
  .jumbotron {
    border-bottom: 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.3/js/select2.min.js"></script>

<div class="container">

  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-12">

      <form class="form-horizontal">
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="type" class="col-sm-5 control-label">I'd like to ride</label>
          <div class="col-sm-5">
            <select name="type" id="type" class="form-control">
              <option>--Select your ride--</option>
              <option value="animals">Animal</option>
              <option value="vehicles">Vehicle</option>
            </select>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="subtype" class="col-sm-5 control-label">More specifically</label>
          <div class="col-sm-5">
            <select name="subtype" id="subtype" class="form-control">
              <option>-- Select type first--</option>
            </select>
          </div>
        </div>
      </form>

    </div>
  </div>

</div>
<!-- /container -->
```

Comment: В какой атрибут? В документации то же не про зависимые списки это про поиск по ajax

Comment: Атрибут `data` - я же написал в ответе. Ладно, не так. в свойство `data` в виде опции select2.

Comment: @Sergalas почему доки должны расписывать какие-то специфичные задачи, которые решают какие-либо другие программисты? Задача плагина предоставить работу с элементами и дать API. А зависимые списки - это уже на логику, которую решает сам конкретный программист, конкретная задача.

Comment: А срабатывание событий тоже прописано: https://select2.org/programmatic-control/methods и https://select2.org/programmatic-control/methods - это нужно в первом селекте, чтобы потом вызвать ajax при событии `select2:select`

Comment: Если лень самому делать, то можете воспользоваться [готовым классом](https://gist.github.com/ajaxray/187e7c9a00666a7ffff52a8a69b8bf31). Пример: https://codepen.io/ajaxray/full/oBPbQe/

Comment: в общем система понятна создаешь options как с обычными зависимыми select и потом инициализируешь select2